# Running multiple querys on YouTube API by looping through title columns of CSV python

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTubes API to get comment data from a list of music videos. The way I have it working right now is by manually typing in my query and then writing the data  to a csv file and repeating for each song like such.

```
query = "song title"


query_results = service.search().list(
        part = 'snippet',
        q = query,
        order = 'relevance', # You can consider using viewCount
        maxResults = 20,
        type = 'video', # Channels might appear in search results
        relevanceLanguage = 'en',
        safeSearch = 'moderate',
        ).execute()
```

What I would like to do is use the title and artist columns from a csv file that I have containing the song titles I am trying to gather data for so I can run the program once without having to manually type in the song each time.

A friend suggested using something like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("metadata.csv")
def songtitle():
for i in data.index:
    title = data.loc[i,'title']
    title = '\"' + title + '\"'
    artist = data.loc[i,'artist']

return(artist, title)
```

But I am not sure how I would make this work because when I run this, it is only returning the final row of data, and even if it did run correctly, how I would handle getting the entire program to repeat it self for every instance of a new song.

Comment: you can use tolist() to convert all values in dataf rame column to a list, `title  = data['title'].tolist()`

Comment: Your friend is wrong, you shouldn’t be iterating over DataFrames manually, and certainly not over the index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save song title and artist to a list, the loop over that list to get details.

```
def get_songTitles():
    data = pd.read_csv("metadata.csv")
    return data['artist'].tolist(),data['title'].tolist()

artist, song_titles  = get_songTitles()
for song in song_titles:
    query_results = service.search().list(
                                            part = 'snippet',
                                            q = song,
                                            order = 'relevance', # You can consider using viewCount
                                            maxResults = 20,
                                            type = 'video', # Channels might appear in search results
                                            relevanceLanguage = 'en',
                                            safeSearch = 'moderate',
                                        ).execute()
```